# how to group 4 html files and 4 css files into 1 html file and 1 css file?

Tags: html, css, merge

How to group/merge 4 html files and 4 css files into 1 html file and 1 css file ? 
I have already copied and pasted the files contents into 1 html file and 1 css file, but the elements are upside down / in a mess. The original css page setting has gone.
(I need to do this only by using html and css) - thanks !

Comment: How do I invent the new google? I can only use google? help? very descriptive isn't it? Did this help? Please provide some example

Comment: Post your Code Please so we can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the CSS part simply paste the code from all files into 1 CSS document. You need to check that you don't have conflicting IDs and Classes otherwise it will mess up your code on the html. Then just link to 1 style sheet rather than multiple.

Each html file acts as a new page? Why do you want to merge this?

Sounds like a copy and paste job. Just have a vigilant eye.

Comment: I have check this : some id and classes are conflicting because they are repeated. I will modify them and them it should be ok. thanks